# Out file using the time during writing of file

Tags: python

I want to write the out file using the time at the writing of the file as the filename.

```
import time, datetime
current_time = time.time()
endtime = current_time + 12*60*60
while current_time < endtime:    

    file_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

    outfile = open ('outfile_{}.txt'.format(file_time),'w')
    outfile.close()
    time.sleep(30)
```

However there is a problem with the file_time. How to define that time?

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124968/out-file-using-the-time-during-writing-of-file/22125029?noredirect=1#comment33567761_22125029):

> thanks for your efforts, but still i get the following error:IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'outfile_2014-03-02_16:36:13.txt'

Comment: Are you getting an error? And if so, do you mind adding it to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also assign current_time while looping:

```
# ...
file_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S')
outfile = open ('outfile_%s.txt' % (file_time),'w')
outfile.close()
time.sleep(30)
current_time = time.time()
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but still i get the following error:IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'outfile_2014-03-02_16:36:13.txt'

Comment: @rockpy Perhaps your OS is not allowing `:` in the file name.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary was going to say that: - `:` is an invalid character on FAT/NTFS :)

Comment: @JonClements That's much more specific, so +1. :-)

Comment: ok then change time stamp format to `file_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S')`, because `:` is not allowed by OS for file names.

Comment: @rockpy I've edited your question to reflect your comment, but please note for the future that you should include relevant information for people to help you out *in your question*... :)

Comment: @vinaykrsharma could you please explain why I should add current_time = time.time() at the end of program. I could not understand at all

Comment: @vinaykrsharma yes, now working but could you please explain why I should add current_time = time.time() at the end of program. I could not understand at all

Comment: First tell me why have you added this condition:
`current_time = time.time()
endtime = current_time + 12*60*60
while current_time < endtime:`?

Comment: @vinaykrsharma because i want to write outfile at every 30 seconds for 12 hours

Comment: For 12 hours right?
But if your current time is not updating after each 30 sec then how your while loop will be terminate after 12 hours. According to your assignment. `current_time` having execution starting timestamp only. So, it will be always `True` for ever

Comment: After 12 hours your program is not going to terminate!